# flatMap on List allows to create a Map with duplicate elements s

Tags: scala

My understanding of Scala immutable Map is that duplicate keys are not allowed. However if flatMap on List then duplicate keys within the Map are generated :

```
 val l = List(1,2)                               //> l  : List[Int] = List(1, 2)
  l.flatMap(m => Map("a" -> m))                   //> res0: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (a,2))
```

But this does not occur if creating a map and populating using `+` operator :

```
  val m = Map("a" -> 1)                           //> m  : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1)
  val update = m +("a" -> 1)                      //> update  : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1)
```

Why does flatMap allow the creation of duplicate keys ?

Comment: In your first example, you are not creating a `Map`, but a `List` of tuples. Nowhere is there a `Map` with duplicate keys involved. Try adding `.toMap`: `l.flatMap(m => Map("a" -> m)).toMap` and you'll see no duplicate keys.

Comment: Look at it this way, the mapping part is creating a list of 2 maps, each map has the same key but they are still distinct, than the flattening is extracting the tuples from the maps. The keys are never duplicated in the map(s)

Comment: Your first example returns a list of pairs, not a map. Are you asking why it returns a list instead?

Comment: m already contains entry with key "a". The default behaviour for a map is to override the values for this key. There nothing changed !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List.flatMap` takes a function that returns a `GenTraversableOnce`. `Map` is a `GenTraversableOnce` of tuples.

You can think of your initial code as equivalent to this:

```
List(1, 2).flatMap(m => List("a" -> m))
```

You never actually work with a `Map` here, just "list-like" things, so there is no notion of key unicity - there isn't even a notion of key.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the meaning of `unicity`?

Comment: Not much to say, really. `Map` guarantees that each key is only going to present once - keys are unique. OP expected that flatMapping into a `Map` would turn the `List` into a `Map`, or enforce the key unicity constraint in a `List` of tuples, but it just doesn't work that way.